# What is the long code for array[random]++

Tags: java, arrays, random, increment

What is the long code for `freq[1+dice.nextInt(6)]++;`
Since `a++` is `a=a+1` then `array[random]++` is ?
Here is my code...

```
Random dice = new Random();
int freq[] = new int[7];

for(int roll=0;roll<1000;roll++){
    ++freq[1+dice.nextInt(6)];
}

System.out.println("Face\tFrequency");

for(int face=1;face<freq.length;face++){
    System.out.println(face + "\t" + freq[face]);
}
```

The sum of Frequency should be exactly 1000.

Comment: What do you mean by "long method"?

Comment: What I mean is "long code". Edited.

Answer (score 4):

```
++freq[1+dice.nextInt(6)];
```

is:

```
int index = 1+dice.nextInt(6); 
++freq[index]; // Increment that position
```

Or, even longer:

```
int index = 1+dice.nextInt(6); 
int value = freq[index];      // Get the value
++value;                      // Increment the value
freq[index] = value;          // Resave
```

Comment: Thank you for reply but what I mean is like this... a++; is a=a+1;

Comment: My update there has the code written out as step-by-step as sanely possible.